# How can we add session id to link page

Tags: asp.net

I downloaded one sample of asp.net.

And when I ran, I see that the link like that:

```
http://localhost/(S(1uld2ekua0uuilxlw15zguus))/login.aspx
```

Can you tell me where we have the string "(S(1uld2ekua0uuilxlw15zguus))"? I checked in the web.config, global.cs but I still don't know where we configure it.

I'm very appriciated for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: No one can answer for your query. this is encrypted string. check it into login class or derived class.

Comment: @SpiderCode, no you are wrong. Its session Id

Comment: that's true. but it will not be same every time. so you cant find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is session id.

What is session id?

Session Id is a unique ID generated by asp.net, to identify the current session.

You are seeing it in a link, because

in web.config file, you'll have this.

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>
<system.web>
```

If you don't need that in the url, you can just set `cookieless=false`

So, it becomes:

```
<system.web>
   <sessionState cookieless="false"></sessionState>
<system.web>
```

Now, the session id will be stored in a cookie.

Comment: thank Amit Joki very much. I changed to false and it worked now.